# Issue uploading a file with cURL to WebSecurityAcademy Lab on PortSwigger.com

Tags: firefox, file-upload, burp-suite, curl

I want to solve an apprentice-level lab on PortSwigger.com focused on file upload vulnerabilities; the lab is called **Remote code execution via web shell upload**. The labs on PortSwigger.com encourage the use of Burp. However, while Burp is convenient, I've been able to complete most of the labs with Firefox's Inspect Elements feature, cURL, FFUF, and my script files (`.zsh`).

In the lab, once you've logged into your account with your credentials (wiener, peter), you are taken to a page that contains a form field. I can upload a MIME type file with the `Upload` button. However, attempting this with cURL leads to the website responding back with `403`:

```
HTTP/2 403                                                                                                                                          
date: Thu, 04 Jan 2024 20:19:53 GMT                                                                                                                 
server: Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu)                                                                                                                      
content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8                                                                                                              
x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN                                                                                                                         
content-encoding: gzip                                                                                                                              
content-length: 130                                                                                                                                 
                                                                                                                                                    
Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.<p><a href="/my-account" title="Return to previous page">� Back to My Account</a></p>
```

I'm using WSL Kali with zshell. The contents for the request headers `-H` and multipart formposts `-F` I collected with Firefox's inspect tool (**Network** tab):

```
#! /user/bin/env zsh

printf "sending request method: POST ..\n"
curl -X POST \
"https://0a03007104c431728258f2ab002d0022.web-security-academy.net/my-account/avatar" \
-H 'Host: 0ad8002a0462a98881c3e838005100e7.web-security-academy.net' \
-H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:121.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/121.0' \
-H 'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8' \
-H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5' \
-H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br' \
-H 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------39790241744060408523443555752' \
-H 'Content-Length: 38849' \
-H 'Origin: https://0ad8002a0462a98881c3e838005100e7.web-security-academy.net' \
-H 'Connection: keep-alive' \
-H 'Referer: https://0ad8002a0462a98881c3e838005100e7.web-security-academy.net/my-account?id=wiener' \
-H 'Cookie: session=xaY31bjOUNnKSpOsO9Pm8jovAqL9d8PR' \
-H 'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1' \
-H 'Sec-Fetch-Dest: document' \
-H 'Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate' \
-H 'Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin' \
-H 'Sec-Fetch-User: ?1' \
-H 'TE: trailers' \
-F 'name=avatar' \
-F 'filename=animeGirl-1.jpg' \
-F avatar=@animeGirl-1.jpg \
-F 'name=user' \
-F 'user=wiener' \
-F 'name=csrf' \
-F 'csrf=WkcqiRG3sycESWznv1lhlBqLeapxHdT0' \
--compressed -i > resp.txt

printf "displaying response: matches found ..\n"
response="(HTTP/2)|(200|302)|(duration)"                                                                                                            
account="(login|my account)|(admin|wiener|carlos)"                                                                                                  
mimeType=".(html|(jpeg|jpg))"                                                                                                                       
formPosts="(form|input type)"                                                                                                                       
                                                                                                                                                    
grep -iE \                                                                                                                                          
"("\                                                                                                                                                
"${response}"\                                                                                                                                  
"${account}"\                                                                                                                                       
"${mimeType}"\                                                                                                                                      
"${formPosts}"\                                                                                                                                     
")" \                                                                                                                                               
resp.txt -A 10
```

Comment: Have you tried to remove `-F 'filename=`  and the redundant `-F 'name=...'`, because curl should create the corresponding `Content-Disposition` out of the values delivered from `-F 'avatar=`, `-F 'user=` and `-F 'csrf=`? (cf https://everything.curl.dev/http/multipart)

Comment: @secf00tprint I tried your approach, but the same response ``403`` is returned.

Comment: What you could do is proxy your curl request (with `-x` option) to Burp and compare it with the same captured from Burp itself out of the application using the browser and foxy proxy. You can compare it in Burp using the comparer. Perhaps this will reveal the missing spots?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To troubleshoot the 403 error during file upload with cURL, you can try:

1. **Check CSRF Token**: The `csrf` token in your script might be outdated.
   Make sure you use a fresh token from a recent request.
2. **Session Cookie**: Your `session` cookie must be valid. If the session has expired or is invalid, you'll get a 403 error.
3. **Correct Endpoint**: Verify the URL in the cURL command. It should match the form action URL.
4. **Headers & Data Format**: Make sure headers and multipart form data are correctly formatted.
5. **File Existence**: Confirm `animeGirl-1.jpg` exists in the working directory.
6. **Boundary Mismatch**: The `Content-Type` header has a boundary, but `-F` in cURL generates its own. Remove the boundary from the header.

Simplified example:

```
#! /usr/bin/env zsh

printf "Sending POST request...\n"

curl -X POST "https://0a03007104c431728258f2ab002d0022.web-security-academy.net/my-account/avatar" \
-H 'Host: 0ad8002a0462a98881c3e838005100e7.web-security-academy.net' \
-H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:121.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/121.0' \
-H 'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8' \
-H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5' \
-H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br' \
-H 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data' \
-H 'Origin: https://0ad8002a0462a98881c3e838005100e7.web-security-academy.net' \
-H 'Connection: keep-alive' \
-H 'Referer: https://0ad8002a0462a98881c3e838005100e7.web-security-academy.net/my-account?id=wiener' \
-H 'Cookie: session=xaY31bjOUNnKSpOsO9Pm8jovAqL9d8PR' \
-H 'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1' \
-H 'Sec-Fetch-Dest: document' \
-H 'Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate' \
-H 'Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin' \
-H 'Sec-Fetch-User: ?1' \
-H 'TE: trailers' \
-F 'avatar=@animeGirl-1.jpg' \
-F 'user=wiener' \
-F 'csrf=WkcqiRG3sycESWznv1lhlBqLeapxHdT0' \
--compressed -i > resp.txt

printf "Displaying response...\n"

grep -iE "(${response}|${account}|${mimeType}|${formPosts})" resp.txt -A 10
```

Make sure to replace the `csrf` token and `session` cookie with current values from your browser.

Comment: The issue was a boundary mismatch. As such, removing the boundary and sending the request enabled the website to respond back with ``200``: "The file avatars/animeGirl-1.jpg has been uploaded". Thanks.